# Extracting particular text

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract all links to videos on a particular WordPress website. Each page has only one video.

Inside each page crawled, there is the following code:

```
<p><script src="https://www.vooplayer.com/v3/watch/video.js"></script>
<iframe id="" voo-auto-adj="true" name="vooplayerframe" style="max-width:100%" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" src="//www.vooplayer.com/v3/watch/watch.php?v=123456;clearVars=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="660" height="410" >
</iframe></p>
```

I would like to extract the text from [here](http://www.vooplayer.com/v3/watch/watch.php?v=123456)

Google Chrome Inspector tells me that this can be addressed as:

- Selector: `//*[@id="post-255"]/div/p/iframe`
- XPath: `#post-255 > div > p > iframe`

But each webpage I am crawling has a different "post" number. They are quite random, hence I cannot easily use the aforementioned selectors.

Comment: Can you post the website url?

Comment: I am afraid no, I am sorry (partially because what I am actually scraping is behind login wall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a dynamic part inside the `id` attribute, you can address it by *partial-matching*:

```
[id^=post] > div > p > iframe
```

where `^=` means "starts with".

XPath alternative:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, "post")]/div/p/iframe
```

---

See also if you can avoid checking for `div` and `p` intermediate elements altogether and do:

```
[id^=post] iframe
//*[starts-with(@id, "post")]//iframe
```

You may additionally check for the iframe name as well:

```
[id^=post] iframe[name=vooplayerframe]
//*[starts-with(@id, "post")]//iframe[@name = "vooplayerframe"]
```